# Is the a better way to do an average of a unordered_multimap key?

Tags: c++, for-loop, unordered-map, c++-chrono, unordered-multimap

I'm searching for get all value of one key in my **unordered_multimap**, which is actually stacking an int and a value who represent an execution time in nanosecs. I need to get all value to replace the multi keys by **one key with an average**.

I tried some code, this one is the most valuable actually :

```cpp
std::unordered_multimap<int, std::chrono::nanoseconds> data;
std::chrono::nanoseconds average;
// *filling my map with value*
for (auto & pair : data){
  auto range = data.equal_range(pair.first);

  for_each (
    range.first,
    range.second,
    [](std::unordered_multimap<int, std::chrono::nanoseconds>::value_type& x){
      average = average + x.second;
    }
  );
  average = average / data.count(pair.first);
  data.erase(pair.first);
  data.insert({pair.first, average});
  }
```

The error i get `error: 'average' is not captured : average = average + x.second;`

Comment: I don't get the question.  Why not just declare `average` at a higher scope?

Comment: `The problem is that average isn't defined out of the for_each loop` - so define average out of the for_each loop. Problem solved!

Comment: `data.erase` within a loop over `data`: Ouch.

Comment: Like the error says, you didn't capture `average`.  Add it to the capture list of the lambda.

Comment: I did change and did the declaration at higher scope, still not working

Comment: I don't understand how to add it to capture list of the lambda, where do i have to put it ?

Comment: `[&average](std::...`. You still have to reset `average` between iterations though, otherwise you'll get wrong results.

Comment: `[](std::unordered_multimap<int, std::chrono::nanoseconds>::value_type& x)` -> `[&average](std::unordered_multimap<int, std::chrono::nanoseconds>::value_type& x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Note that removing entries from a `std::unordered_multimap` within a ranged-for over it is undefined behaviour. It's safer to fill a different container.

```
std::unordered_multimap<int, std::chrono::nanoseconds> data;
// *filling my map with value*

std::unordered_multimap<int, std::chrono::nanoseconds> new_data;
for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it){
  auto range = data.equal_range(it->first);

  auto average = std::accumulate (
    range.first,
    range.second,
    std::chrono::nanoseconds{0},
    [](auto sum, auto & x){
      return sum + x.second;
    }
  ) / std::distance(range.first, range.second);

  new_data.emplace(key, average);
}
data.swap(new_data);
```

Alternatively, if you have C++17, [`std::transform_reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce).

```
  std::transform_reduce(
    range.first,
    range.second,
    std::chrono::nanoseconds{0},
    std::plus<>{},
    [](auto & x) { return x.second; }
  )
```

Comment: I tried this, but had a lot of errors, can't compile at all

Comment: Is `emplace` really always safe? I suppose it cannot cause rehashing since the size doesn't increase, but is the new element's iterator guaranteed to be ordered before `it` returned from `erase`?

Comment: That working well, i did change after your edit, all good !! Thank you

Comment: @walnut maybe? probably safer to fill a `decltype(data) new_data;` and `data.swap(new_data);` afterwards

Comment: @Caleth Yes, that would have been my suggestion. Also allows dropping the `erase` and using an ordinary iterator loop. According to cppreference only since C++14 is `erase` guaranteed to preserve the order of the iterators and it doesn't say anything about `emplace` in that regard.